# Custome Node-RED : Check authentication and custom id of flow

Tags: node-red

I have some task with node-red.

Task1 : How i can change default id of flow? Example : c70bd37e.f4de8 -> id1

Task2 : How can i check permission or login from another web when i redirect to node-red dashboard?
Anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

1. You can generate flow files independently of Node-RED and generate any IDs you want as long as they are unique, but anything modified or created by the editor will use the form you have shown here. The only way to change it would be to modify the core code.
2. This will very much depend on how the sites are arranged, e.g. if they are both on the same host or are both hosted on the same root domain. But in either case you will have to use a custom `httpNodeMiddleware` function in the `settings.js` file to check a header/cookie value. The function should be of the form of a ExpressJS middleware function.

Comment: thanks @hardillb, but my question about task 1 not extractly. In task 1, i want to get id of flow to save to my database, not to change id, can you show me how can i do this.

Comment: It answers the question that was asked. If you have a different question open a new question. (When you do include a LOT more detail about what and why you want to achieve and what you have already tried and how it didn't work)